# Resettable guild cooldown for discord.py slash command

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I am trying to add a cooldown to a slash command I have written in discord.py. The cooldown will need to be reset in certain cases, so I cannot use the `@app_commands.checks.cooldown` decorator and instead will have to write a custom cooldown. I have written some code for this but it hasn't worked so far.

My Code:

```py
    def get_ratelimit(self, message) -> typing.Optional[int]:
        bucket = commands.CooldownMapping.from_cooldown(1, 20, commands.BucketType.guild).get_bucket(message)
        return bucket.update_rate_limit()

    @app_commands.command(name="cooldown_test", description="Testing cooldown")
    async def cooldown_test(self, inter):
        limit = self.get_ratelimit(inter)
        if limit == None:
            # some code here as well as condition to reset cooldown

        else:
            await inter.response.send_message(f"This is on a 20 second cooldown.", ephemeral=True)
```

The code does run without errors, but `get_ratelimit` returns `None` everytime, therefore bypassing the cooldown. I'm looking for help to fix this issue so that the cooldown works normally (one use per guild every 20 seconds) but can still also be reset in the code. Thanks in advance!

Comment: bump. does anyone have a solution?